# Did apache poi has excel application dependency?

Tags: java, selenium, apache-poi

I have a VM where I need to run my test scripts, but it doesn't have excel application installed. I used Apache POI in my selenium script to read and write excelsheet. Will Apache POI work even without excel application?

Comment: Hope my answer help you.. If it please accept it so other can get help from it

Comment: What happened when you tried it out for yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it works without Excel application in your VM.

Apache POI is a popular API that allows programmers to create, modify, and display MS Office files using Java programs

Comment: Half your answer is incorrect - Apache POI contains *zero APIs which interact with Excel* ! Apache POI doesn't require Excel at all